# Android Espresso test memory overhead?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-espresso

I have a long-running test that basically exercises a reasonably common real-life use case of the production app. It failed after approximately 15 hours, and the failure was due to a `OutOfMemoryError` while inflating a `View`.

My question is, how likely is it for `Espresso` to introduce enough memory overhead to trigger `OutOfMemoryError`s that would normally not happen in production?

There isn't much online about `Espresso`'s memory footprint or overhead, hence the question here :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner.html#using-android-test-orchestrator could help you

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano thanks but I didn't see anything on that page that can help me understand `Espresso`'s memory overhead. Did you see anything there that could help me?

Comment: Orchestrator runs each test in its own invocation of Instrumentation, so most probably you'll get rid of the OOME.